# Wondering about a control name

Tags: iphone, uicontrol

please i am wondering about the name of that control in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEAkVCouI_Y (stop it in the 48 seconds) where the user can set parameters of his search (the  `<peu importe>`  field and that shaft in front).
Thx in advance :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UISearchBar is what you're looking for.
This also has SectionIndexTitles which is part of the UITableViewDataSource protocol.

Comment: Hi, actually i don`t either know what is its name, i will check it, thx Mike :)